# If condition not working in bootstrap switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap switch.
But If condition is not working in switch.

```
setTimeout(function(){
            $('#oconnect').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event, state) {
                    var state1 = $('#oconnect').bootstrapSwitch('state'); 
                    alert(state1);  
                    if(state1 === "true")
                    {
                        alert(1);
                        $('.user_spec_div').css('display','block');    
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert(2);
                        $('.user_spec_div').css('display','none');    
                    }
            });
        }, 500);
```

I got the changed value of state1.
It returns `true` and `false`.

But if I'm checking through `if(state1 === "true")` or `if(state1 == "true")` it not working. It always goes in to else condition.

Comment: It's more likely that `state` is a boolean, so use `if (state1) {...`

Comment: oh great thank you for the quick reply. I'm totally forget about boolean it's working :)

Comment: Glad to help. I added it as an answer for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://bootstrapswitch.com/options.html), `state` is a boolean value. The problem is therefore caused by your attempts to compare it to a string.

Instead change your `if` statement to this:

```
if (state1) {
  // your code here...
}
```

In fact you can make the code even more succinct by giving the boolean `state` value, which is directly passed to the event handler, to the `toggle()` method, like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#oconnect').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(e, state) {
    $('.user_spec_div').toggle(state);
  });
}, 500);
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.  It's working perfectly. :)

Comment: No problem. I just updated the answer to give you a much more simple implementation of the logic too.